# Is it a valid kernel?

Tags: integration

Suppose we have a valid psd kernel $k(x, y)$, then we set

$\psi(x, y) = ak(x, y) + bk(x, x_0) + ck(x_0, y) + dk(x_0, x_0)$

where $a, b, c, d \geq 0$. Thus, is $\psi(x, y)$ a valid psd kernel? As we know that a valid psd kernel has to satisfy Mercer's condition

$\int\int k(x, y)f(x)f(y)d_xd_y \geq 0$, where $f(x)$ is any square-integrable function.

This question comes from myself.

Comment: Is it symmetric?

Comment: hi @nullgeppetto, a valid kernel must be symmetric. so $k(x, x_0) = k(x_0, x)$